# powershell script to behave like vim or nano?

Tags: windows, powershell, text-editor

Does Powershell have the capacity to generate some kind of terminal-based text editor program? I am switching to Windows because it supports a few programs I can't use otherwise; but I am having trouble discovering some sort of way to edit text files directly from Powershell. Is it possible to create a terminal-based text editor with a Powershell script; and if not is there a *simple* alternative?

Comment: Why don't you just install [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), as it has a Windows version too? Add it to path and you should be all set.

Comment: @vonPryz Aw gee thanks! Will you please put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just install [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), as it has a Windows version too? Add it to path and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest **`micro`** which is a powershell/ cmd/ terminal based text editor for `Windows and other OS`

> **[image: micro]** https://micro-editor.github.io/

Because `micro` is flexible cut/copy/paste same keyboard shortcut as `notepad`. The best part is, it has color highlighter sensitive to programming language. Here is an image

Note: don't forget the add the micro.exe path to environment variable.

Command to open a file from cmd:

```
micro ./file.xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

You use chocolately if it is installed on your powershell if you don’t have it just search for it online

```
Choco install nano
```

After this you can use nano

Then just

```
nano filenam
```

If it exists it edit it and if it doesn’t it create a new file